# How can I stack these items on top of each others at the bottom of a vertical bar?

Tags: vertical-alignment, typography

All my attempts have failed so far. I have the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
y &= y_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{ x^n}{n!}  \, f_n(x,y) \bigg\vert_{x=x_0,y=y_0}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

I tried `align*` there, but LaTeX complained.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
y &= y_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{ x^n}{n!}  \, f_n(x,y) \bigg\vert_{\begin{align*}x&=x_0\\y&=y_0\end{align*}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;(amsmath) trying to recover with `aligned'. \end{align*}
```

I am using LuaTeX in [TeX Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX_Live) 2022. I have reached the end of my LaTeX skill level with this.

Comment: Have you tried `\bigg\vert_{\substack{x=x_0\\ y=y_0}}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just use `\substack`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  y &= y_0 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \, f_n(x, y) \bigg\vert_{\substack{x =x_0 \\ y=y_0}}
\end{align*}
    
\end{document}
```